# The multi-part identifier “System.Data.DataRowView” could not be bound in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I made two comboboxes. One of them depends on data from the other. When the first one selected index changes I need take the new value and use it to update the other. Here is what I have so far for the first combobox:

```
Try
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from tb_section ", connSql)

    connSql.Open()

    Dim dr As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable
    dr.Fill(table)

    compsec.DataSource = table
    compsec.DisplayMember = "sec_name"
    compsec.ValueMember = "sec_code"

Catch ex As Exception

    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    connSql.Close()

Finally
    connSql.Close()

End Try
```

And here is code for the other combo box:

```
Public Sub all_group_list(sectioncode)

    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from tb_group where sec_code= " & sectioncode.ToString, connSql)

        connSql.Open()

        Dim dro As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable
        dro.Fill(table)

        compgroup.DataSource = table
        compgroup.DisplayMember = "group_name"
        compgroup.ValueMember = "group_code"

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        connSql.Close()

    Finally
        connSql.Close()

    End Try
End Sub
```

When the first combobox index changes I run this code:

```
 Private Sub compsec_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles compsec.SelectedIndexChanged

    connSql.Close()

    all_group_list(compsec.SelectedValue.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you having with this code? We see the code, and we see what you're trying to do, but you haven't explained how it fails.

Comment: the problem is i have this error msg when application run ( it come 2 time ). but when close the error msg the code run correctly (same as i want result )

Comment: What error message? We need to see the exact message, and you should edit that information into the original question. Though I suspect the problem is you haven't yet set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties the first time you assign to the DataSource, and so it doesn't know what to do. Set those other properties _first_, set the DataSource property _after_. And if that's true, the code in my answer will already fix your problem.

Comment: i have this error only when put it in combo box selected index changed event . but if i put the code in form load i not get the error but other combo box not get his list from second one

Comment: Okay. So edit that information (and the other stuff I asked for) into the original question.

Comment: the error message is The multi-part identifier System.Data.DataRowView could not be bound

Comment: thank you . i use your code - the code run correctly with no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what problem you're actually having, but there are several fixes in the code below. Name: **don't use string concatenation to put data into an SQL command!** Also, don't try to re-use the same connection object throughout an application. Only share the connection string, as sharing the same connection object interferes with the connection pooling feature in ADO.Net. Further, the DataAdapter will handle opening and closing the connection for you, and a `Using` block, rather than a `Finally` block, is the best way to be sure the connection closes if an exception is thrown.

```vb
Try
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Using cn As new SqlConnection(connSql.ConnectionString), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand("select sec_name, sec_code from tb_section", cn), _
          da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds)
    End Using

    compsec.DisplayMember = "sec_name"
    compsec.ValueMember = "sec_code"
    compsec.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

.

```vb
Public Sub all_group_list(sectioncode)
    Try
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(connSql.ConnectionString), _
              cmd As New SqlCommand("select group_name, group_code from tb_group where sec_code= @SectionCode", cn), _
              da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            'Had to guess at column type/length here. Use the actual column definition from your database
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SectionCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = sectioncode
            da.Fill(ds)
        End Using

        compgroup.DisplayMember = "group_name"
        compgroup.ValueMember = "group_code"
        compgroup.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

.

```vb
Private Sub compsec_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles compsec.SelectedIndexChanged
    all_group_list(compsec.SelectedValue.ToString())
End Sub
```